What is the scriptural proof that Dattatreya is a trinity combination Avatara?
When we see Lord Dattatreya, we will see him as 3 faced person, And combination, Avatar of Brahma Vishnu Siva, but when we go on reading the Puran, we can find that Dattatreya is Avatar of Lord Vishnu only. What is this Scriptural proof that he is a combination Avataara ?
[Note: anyone what to quote Dattatreya stotram of narada purana they should show present it is contain in narada purana]

Dattatreya is the avatars of Vishnu, not of the Trinity. The 3 faced 6 armed form which is commonly described to be of Dattatreya is actually (according to the Shilpasastra text Aparajitapriccha) a decorational icon called Hari-hara-pitamaha.

Dattatreya is Vishnu alone.

Markandeya Purana -

“Thus three sons were born of her, being portions of Brahmā, Śiva and Viṣṇu. Brahmā became Soma, Viṣṇu was born as Dattātreya, Śiva was born as Durvāsas, through the boon granted by the gods.”

Canto XVII, Markandeya Purana.


Srimad Bhagavatam -

“Thus Soma was born with a portion of Brahmā, Datta, the master of Yoga, with that of Viṣṇu, while Durvāsas with the portion of Sankara.”

Chapter 1, 4th Skandha, Srimad Bhagavatam.


Vishnu Purana -

“This prince propitiated the sage Dattātreya, the descendant of Atri, who was a portion of Viṣṇu, and solicited and obtained from him these boons—a thousand arms; never acting unjustly; subjugation of the world by justice, and protecting it equitably; victory over his enemies; and death by the hands of a person renowned in the three regions of the universe.”

Chapter XI, Book IV, Vishnu Purana.


Garuda Purana -

“In his sixth incarnation he was born as the son of Atri and communicated to Alarka, Pralhada (Prahlada?) and others, the knowledge of Anvikshiki (metaphaysics) obtained by him from Anasuya.”

Chapter 1, Agastya Samhita, Garuda Purana.


Padma Purana -

“The king, the lord of Māhiṣmatī, went to that brāhmaṇa Dattātreya (who was) actually Viṣṇu, who lived on the Sahya mountain, and asked him (about the bath in Māgha).”
Chapter 126, Uttara Khanda, Padma Purana.
6. Brahma Purana -
“A further manifestation of Viṣṇu the great Ātman, in the nature of a living being, is well known as Dattatreya. He was equipped with great forbearance.”

Chapter 104, Brahma Purana.


Dattatreya Upanishad -

"Once Brahma the creator asked Lord Narayana about the efficacy of the Taraka-Mantra to which the latter replied: "Always think of Me and My glory, and be in commune with Me in the attitude 'I am Datta, the great Lord.' Such ones who meditate thus do not swirl in the recurring course of worldly existence."

Dattatreya Upanishad of Atharvaveda.


Harivamsa ( Mahabharata) -

"The Great Vishnu, the soul of all, next incarnated himself as the highly forgiving Dattatreya."

Chapter 41, Harivamsa Parva, Harivamsa.


Jabala Darshana Upanishad -

"God Dattatreya is the reincarnation of the four armed Vishnu and he is the ruler of the world. Sankrithi is a great devotee and a sage and is an expert in yoga and also a disciple of Dattatreya."

Jabala Darshana Upanishad of Samaveda.

